# jQuery Mobile Method Failing Silently

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, telerik

I am in the process of writing a mobile app with the jQuery Mobile Framework and have hit an issue that doesn't make any sense. I have the following function at the bottom of my page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert('binding');
        $("li.item, li.altitem").bind("dblclick", function () {
        alert('here');
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("item_", "");
        window.radopen("/review-detail.aspx?id=" + id, "ReviewDetailWindow");                    
    });
});
```

Essentially what this function is doing is when the page loads it cycles through all <li> tags with a class of "item" or "altitem" and adds a double-click event which opens a modal dialog. This function works great the first time I double-click (eventually double-tap) one of the list items, but subsequent double-clicks are ignored. I don't see any JavaScript errors occurring so I'm not entirely certain what's going on or where to begin. This appears to be a cross-browser issue too

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why, but I've got it working now. Apparently I shouldn't have used the $(document).ready() method call because the mobile framework doesn't officially support it. The updated (and functioning) JS is:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.item, li.altitem", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("item_", "");
    var win = radopen("/review-detail.aspx?id=" + id, "ReviewDetailWindow");                
    win.center();
});
```